# Cant compile String to INT

Tags: java, string, int

Currently im using this method, however the output works just for the first 2 players rather than for example 3 or 4.

- I would like to know what makes this code work just for the two players, and why it does not sort the rest. The algorithm for sorting in this code works now.

  ```
  public static void questions(String[] question, String[] answer, int n) {

      String[] name = new String[n];  // Player Names 
      int[] playerscore = new int[n]; // Argument for Score
      String[] que = new String[question.length]; //Questions for Loops



          /* --------------------------- For loop for number of players --------------------------- */ 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      playerscore[i] = 0;
      name[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name player "+ (i+1) +"?");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello : "+ name[i] + " Player number " +(i+1)+ ". I hope your ready to start!");


          /* --------------------------- Loop in Loop for questions --------------------------- */ 
      for (int x=0; x<question.length; x++) {
          que[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question[x]);
              if(que[x].equals(answer[x]))
                  {

                      playerscore[i] = playerscore[i] + 1;

                  }

      else {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong!");
           }

              } // End for loop for Question





  // declare array and initialise with random elements

  // print it out
  for (int y=0; y<size; y++)
  {
      System.out.println("\nPlayer: "+(i+1)+ " Name: "+name[i]+" Score:"+playerscore[i]+" out of 5."); 
  }
  System.out.println();

  sort(playerscore);        

  // print it out again

  for (int y=0; y<size; y++)
  {
      System.out.println("\nPlayer: "+(i+1)+ " Name: "+name[i]+" Score:"+playerscore[i]+" out of 5."); 
  }
  System.out.println();







          /* --------------------------- Loop in Loop for questions --------------------------- */ 



         } // End for loop for player number

            } //End method questions




  while (!sorted)
  {
     // array potentially sorted 
      sorted = true;

     //traverse array switching ill-ordered pairs
     for (int i=0; i < playerscore.length-1; i++)
     {
          if (playerscore[i] > playerscore [i+1])
          {
            // swap them
            int tmp = playerscore[i+1];
            playerscore[i+1] = playerscore[i];
            playerscore[i] = tmp;
            // array wasn't sorted
            sorted = false;

            // write array so can see whats happening
            write_array(playerscore);

           }
     }
  }
  ```

  }

  static void write_array(int[] playerscore)
  {
      for (int i=0; i < playerscore.length; i++)
      {
               System.out.print(playerscore[i]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }

Comment: Then you should show us the `sort()` method.

Comment: Ummm, yes, you can't convert a `String` to an `int` directly (you need to use a parsing method like [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)).  So if you want to convert an array of `String` to an array of `int`, you will need to do that on each item in the array.  I'm assuming that `sort` is a method that takes an `int[]` parameter, although I have to guess because you've chosen to hide that important piece of info from us.

Comment: If there is a sort method `void sort( int[] x)` it cannot be used to sort a `String[]`.

Comment: Actually, if you're sorting by name, why is there an `int[]` involved at all?  Or are you actually trying to sort by score?  If you're trying to sort by score, why are you calling `sort(name)`?

Comment: Actually now i realised thank you.. I actually do want to sort this out by Playerscore. Just trying to figure it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Arrays.sort( x );
```

for String[] as well as int[]. Don't roll your own...

java.util.Arrays contains several definitions of sort: That's called overloading. You can't do the same by writing a single sort method.

Comment: Where should i use it? In the Questions method ?

Comment: Wherever you call your sort method - remove the definition of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using generics and the Collection API, it has a sort Method on it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: OP has arrays. Don't make it more complicated.

Comment: I guess it is object oriented, currently im just on procedural programming. Don't want to make it complicated for myself.